# How to show different stroke in same line in rechart?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I am using `recharts` with `react`, and I need suggestion as to how I can use different strokes in the same `Line` in a `LineChart`. For example, it can show a solid line till current date, and a dashed line for a future date (think as the prediction of some data).

Comment: So what you mean is you want to access a specific point in the Line programatically?

Comment: Hmm, based on X-axis (or may be Y axis) value actually.  If the line cross that limit, it becomes dashed

Comment: Indeed, but you would have to change the prop `strokeDasharray` in the `<Line />` compoenent anyway. So i guess it is just a matter of how to access a certain data point from there, right?

Comment: Yes, I think so

Comment: Thing is `strokeDasharray` is for full `Line` and I dont see a way to alter it data point wise for a single line.

Answer (score 6):

I have approached problem same as @fjcero did, I was also struggling with the same problem. but since the link is no longer working, created a new fiddle.

I structed Data like below, so when we don't need a line for prediction or current simply use a null and at the intersection on `data[2]` the prediction and current are same variables.

```
    const data = [
      {month: "Feb", historical:4, current: 5, prediction:null},
      {month: "Mar", historical:11, current: 10.5, prediction:null},
      {month: "April", historical:12, current: 11, prediction:11},
      {month:"June", historical:13, current:null, prediction:13},
      {month:"July", historical:14, current:null, prediction:15},
      {month:"August", historical:15, current:null, prediction:17}
];
```

And than used three Line components to draw line for current, historical and prediction with one for prediction having a prop `strokeDasharray="3 3"`  for dashed line.

Here is the link to fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/jassMarok/q6gLxoz4/

```js
// JS Source Only
const {LineChart, Area, Line, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, Legend, ReferenceLine, ComposedChart} = Recharts;
const data = [
      {month: "Feb", historical:4, current: 5, prediction:null},
      {month: "Mar", historical:11, current: 10.5, prediction:null},
     {month: "April", historical:12, current: 11, prediction:11},
      {month:"June", historical:13, current:null, prediction:13},
      {month:"July", historical:14, current:null, prediction:15},
      {month:"August", historical:15, current:null, prediction:17}
];
const SimpleLineChart = React.createClass({
 render () {
   return (
     <ComposedChart width={600} height={300} data={data}
            margin={{top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5}}>
       <XAxis dataKey="month" />
       <YAxis />
       <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3"/>
       <Tooltip/>
       <ReferenceLine y={15} label="Target Seats" stroke="red" />
       <Area type="monotone" dataKey="current" fill="#8884d8" stroke="#8884d8" />
       <Line type="monotone" dataKey="historical" stroke="#82ca9d" />
       <Line type="monotone" dataKey="prediction" stroke="#8884d8" strokeDasharray="3 3" />
      </ComposedChart>
    );
  }
})
```

Comment: I think it would be better if you share the code here instead of jsfiddle since we are not in control of jsfiddle availability.

Comment: @Pankwood added just the source code but it will not run on stackoverflow, does that makes it better ?

Comment: Yep. The link and the code together is looking amazing. Tks

Comment: Interesting to notice that the docs say it is [strokeDashArray](https://recharts.org/en-US/api/Line#strokeDashArray), but in fact, it works only if you write it as strokeDasharray.

Answer (score 1):

I approached the problem generating 2 different lines, with dataset based on null and intersection values. Here is an example:

```
<LineChart
  width={600}
  height={300}
  data={history}
  margin={{ top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5 }}
>
  <Line type="monotone" dataKey="volume" stroke="#82ca9d" dot={false} />
  <Line
    type="monotone"
    dataKey="volumef"
    strokeDasharray="5 5"
    stroke="red"
    dot={false}
  />
</LineChart>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/alidingling/exh283uh/